# How to git show for a specific file?

Tags: git

I want to see what was changed in a specific commit.

No Problem

```
git show 123456
```

But this commit has a ton of changes, I want to see only changes for one specific file

Let me try this

```
git show 123456:/foo/bar/my.file
```

Well, works. But not as expected. The above command will show me the entire file in rev. 123456 - but I want to see the diff for this rev (as it is for `git show 123456`).

Comment: So you want to diff the commit at 123456 and 123456^ instead, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "--" separator:

```
git show 123456 -- /foo/bar/my.file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff 123456 123456^ -- /foo/bar/my.file
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `git diff` command, then, if you want to see the diff between commits:

```
$ git diff <commit1>..<commit2> -- <your_file_path>
```

Comment: @Brettetete:  No, if you want to diff between two revisions, you need two SHAs.

Answer (score 0):

```
git show HEAD...HEAD~1 -- *my.file
```